# vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer does not work when used with an image created by application

Tags: vulkan

I had created my own swap chain with vkCreateImage by allocating its appropriate memory (VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT). And got the image data after vkQueueSubmit and vkQueueWaitIdle by mapping the memory associated with it.

Due to the advantages of staging buffers, I created the above memory with VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT and did a vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer in Command Buffers but the result is all values 0. But if I just associate a vkCreateBuffer to the above image and do vkCmdCopyBuffer I do get all the rendered image.

Is this an expected behavior that we cannot do vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer unless it's a system swapchain?

Edit 1:

I am rendering to vkCreateImage with memory type VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT. The things is that when I do vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer the image data in this buffer is all 0.
Now when I create a vkCreateBuffer and bind to the above image memory with vkBindBufferMemory. After which I do vkCmdCopyBuffer, I do get the image data. Why does vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer not work ? Is it that since I am allocating memory for image? Because in case of swapchain images where we do not allocate memory, works fine with vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer. Why do I need extra overhead of binding a buffer to my allocated image memory to make this work.

Comment: "*I had created my own swap chain*" You cannot create a swap chain from your own memory. The memory for swap chain images is owned by the implementation, not you.

Comment: @NicolBolas I did not use system's swap chain but created images and using fences, so in all which will act like a swap chain of the system. I am doing an offscreen rendering with these images.

Comment: My point is that, however much it may "act like a swap chain", it *isn't* a swap chain. It's just some images you've created that you are rendering to. In any case, your question doesn't make it clear which objects you're allocating with which kinds of memory. Perhaps you could post some code to clarify exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Short answer: No, swapchain `VkImage` or not does not matter. Problem must be elsewhere. TBH I am bit confused by the description. So do you copy it or do you map it to host. Why is the Image `HOST_VISIBLE`? Which of the memories is the `DEVICE_LOCAL` one? Is this pushing CPU side image to Vulkan or other way around?

Comment: Better. There is nothing obviously wrong based on your description. Do you have validation layers properly enabled? Is source code of this available?

Comment: @krOoze I tried on Mali and did get the image data. Some issue with Adreno, maybe setting something wrong. Will put validation layers.
I wanted to know whether the method(steps) I tried were valid ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are paying attention to image layouts.  You may need a barrier to transition the layouts appropriately.

You might also turn on the validation layers to see if they catch anything.

(I am confused by the description as well, so sorry for my vague answer.)

Comment: Can be anything. Synchronization, invalidation(for non-coherent) or usage flags too.